# Write Log Messages to Third Party REST service with NLog

Tags: web-services, nlog, octopus-deploy

Looking for a way to send messages with NLog to a third party REST api.

Most of the examples I have seen how to post log messages to a service in which the endpoint can be modified to fit what NLog wants.

For some context to the problem.  We are using Octopus deploy.  One of the components to our app is SSRS reports that are surfaced through the app.  The RDL files deployed to the SSRS server require dependent data to be written to the app database.

We have a command line tool that handles that - but it requires someone to run the tool.

I want to add the tool as a the last step in the deployment process of the RDL files.  All simple enough.

The challenge is the tool writes problems / exceptions to a log file.  What I want to do is put another target in the NLog config so that I can post those messages back to the Octopus server - this way the Release Engineers deploying don't have to log in to the remote server to diagnose problems.

Octopus has a very robust REST api (they even have .NET client already written).  Is there a way to wrap this client in a NLog ServiceTarget extension?

Comment: write a custom target? See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

Comment: Perfect.  That is what I was looking for.